# how to convert data table row to string

Tags: sql, database, wpf, vb.net, datatable

```
Dim a As New ClsKoneksi
    Dim query As String
    query = "SELECT KodeBarang FROM Barang"
    dt = a.executequerydata(query)
    Dim names As New List(Of String)
        For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count() - 1
            Dim brngname As String = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows(i))
            names.Add(brngname)
        Next
        For i = 0 To names.Count() - 1
            BARANGLIST.Items.Add(names(i).ToString)
        Next
```

try to insert value from data table row to wpf combobox and
i try to convert row in datatable to string but it produced "System.data.datarow" in brngname variable. how can i convert row in data table to string?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhCOE.png)

Comment: You are probably asking how to get that *field's* value, not convert the entire row, no matter how many fields it has, to a string.

Comment: What are you trying to do though? You are converting the value to string *twice*, then adding it to a list? `Convert.ToString` is essentially a call to `ToString()`. If you wanted to read the results into a List you could use LINQ, eg `var list=dt.AsEnumerable().Select(row=>row.Field<string>("KodeBarang").ToList();`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos your LINQ example is C#; OP tagged vb.net

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i added the return value for "dt" table. what i was trying to do is, add item to list from dt table that populated by query to access database, then add it to BARANGLIST which is a combobox in xaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of converting entire `DataRow` object to string, get field value from that row:

```
Dim brngname As String = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows(i).Item("KodeBarang"))
```

`names` list seems redundant:

```
Dim a As New ClsKoneksi
Dim query As String
query = "SELECT KodeBarang FROM Barang"
dt = a.executequerydata(query)

For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count() - 1
    BARANGLIST.Items.Add(dt.Rows(i).Item("KodeBarang"))
Next
```

Comment: dt is actually a data table and i only query column "KodeBarang", i already view it in visual studio it produced only that table with the default "Table" name and all KodeBarang data but when i convert it to string , why it produce system.data.datarow(?)

Comment: `System.Data.DataRow` is default string representation for any DataRow. it doesn't have meaningful override

Comment: thanks! this solve the problem , i forgot the "item" in  dt.rows(i).item(i). i thought dt.rows(0) refer to row 0 and directly take the value without need to specify the column

Answer (score 0):

The error you get is due to the fact there's no available conversion from the  `System.data.datarow` datatype to the `string` datatype, so that the `Covert.ToString` function cannot do the job (note that `dt.Rows(i)` is a datarow, not a string!).
Even in your example you have just one field (i.e. one column), a more general solution may consist in serializing the entire table by looping within columns while looping within rows , and building a string using your preferred columns/rows separators.

Comment: This isn't an *error*. [Covert.ToString()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,1801) is essentially a call to `ToString()`. DataRow doesn't override `ToString()` so `Object.ToString()` is called which returns the type's name

Comment: @Panagiotis: yes, the term "error" I used was not correct.

Comment: i added the picture of the table. if dt.rows(0) not refer to a row then how to get the value of data from a row  ?

Comment: `dt.rows(0)` IS a row. It IS NOT a string. A row contains the field values (which can be string, or they can be converted to a string). @ASh has already answered: `dt.Rows(i).Item(...)`